# Creating SQL database for Applet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, applet

I am having a simple Applet running on a Eclipse. My requirement is to store some values(random id, name, account number) in SQL database from this applet. Later, I also need access this DB from a servlet, which is running on the same setup.

I am new to this and couldn't get any link for this development. Could someone give/guide me steps to create MySQL DB specific for my requirement and access from Applet(running on eclipse) and store values in it?

Comment: I voted to close this as 'too broad' and I think that applies to your searches for tutorials on the matter as well.  Look instead for tutorials covering each part of the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly refer below link.

I'm sure you'll get your answer.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/samples/jdbc/s-Applt-java.htm

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
    connectionProps.put("password", this.password);

    if (this.dbms.equals("mysql")) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:" + this.dbms + "://" +
                   this.serverName +
                   ":" + this.portNumber + "/",
                   connectionProps);
    } else if (this.dbms.equals("derby")) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:" + this.dbms + ":" +
                   this.dbName +
                   ";create=true",
                   connectionProps);
    }
    System.out.println("Connected to database");
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: This is good for accessing DB in Applet. May I know, how to create MySQL DB as well from scratch?

Comment: I would like to create mysql database from MySql Workbench and write some data from Applet. Please guide me the procedure or share me the links.

Comment: you can simply do it by writing jdbc connection code inside your applet file. I've edited my answer and kept code to connect with database too.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question, Should I have created a mysql database before trying your jdbc connection code right?

Comment: Yes, you need to create database and provide database name, database server, username and password inside this code.

Comment: and if you find this answer is useful then you can accept it and upvote it as per stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: Great! One more doubt, Hope I can use MySql Workbench to create MySql DB for accessing from this servlet right? Because, I have MySql Workbench installed and asked to use it.

Comment: even you can use sqllite tools for the same.

Comment: I have told to use MySql Workbench as per the requirement, that's why asking.

Comment: you can use that too.

Comment: I couldn't successfully done it, so i created a separate issue in this query-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997519/nullpointerexception-error-when-applet-accessing-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you break the problem into pieces.

Start with the database interface.  Write a Java interface that describes all the methods you want to execute.  SQL databases usually let you Create, Read, Update, and/or Delete (CRUD).

```
package persistence;

public interface DataAccess<K, V> {
   V find(K key);
   List<V> find();
   K save(V value);
   int update(V value);
   int delete(V value);
};
```

Implement this interface with a Java POJO.  Test it thoroughly and put it aside.

Give an instance of that DAO to your servlet so it can access the database.  Now all the servlet needs to do is listen for HTTP requests, bind and validate the parameters, figure out where to send the request, and package up the response.  The database is already sorted.

Last step is the applet.  Make it talk to your servlet by making requests to the URLs that the servlet expects and pass the HTTP parameters.